# How to fix instance of extension returning nil?

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, swift4.2

I am trying to implement like functionality just like facebook. I have like buttons in prototype cells in which a user can click to like. I created the like functionality in my model class and I am trying to access it in my tableviewcell class.I created the like functionality in an extension in my model class. I am trying to call the extension in another class but the reference to the extension is returning nil.

this is the extension in my model class

```
extension UserPostsModel{

  func like()
{
    likez += 1
   userPosts.child(keyz!).child("likes").setValue(likez)
}
}
```

this is how I am calling it in my tableviewcell class

```
//feedposts is returning nil 
var feedposts: UserPostsModel!

@IBAction func likeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    feedposts.like()
}
```

when the user clicks on the button the like functionality should be implemented but the app crashes because the extension is returning nil

Comment: Did you set or initialize the model for cell? Like cell.feedposts = Feedposts()

Comment: No I didn't...where should I initialise it @DenFav

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize UserPostsModel class.

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Or in cell like

```
var feedposts: UserPostsModel = UserPostsModel()
```

But in cellForRow methods will be a bit better practice

Currently the property is unwrapped with !(you are saying to compiler that it cannot be nil, but you didn't set it and it IS nil)